# React, flash of content from visited routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm toying with React and I've encountered a thing I don't quite understand — every time I navigate between the routes I get to see what I think is a flash of a previous state of the component. I've built a simple blog and when I'm navigating between, for instance, different posts there's this a flash of previous post content like title and body. It gets replaced immediately with the new state after the requested post is fetched, but it is noticeable and very unpleasant.
Why is this happens? Where is this data might be stored? Thanks in advance.

Here's the Post component.

```
class Post extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    params: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.displayName = 'Post';
    this.state = PostStore.getState();
    this.onChange = ::this.onChange;
    this._deletePost = ::this._deletePost;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    toastr.success(`id is: ${this.props.params.id}`);
    PostStore.listen(this.onChange);
    PostActions.getPost(this.props.params.id);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    PostStore.unlisten(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }

  _deletePost() {
    PostActions.deletePost(this.props.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
      <h1>{this.state.post.title}</h1>
      <h3>{this.state.post.author}</h2>
      <p>{this.state.post.body}</p>
      ...
    );
  }
}

export default Post;
```